# Is Delta H = Delta U for bomb calorimeter or Delta H = Delta U + Delta n(g)RT?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

As we know volume change in bomb calorimeter is zero. So if we use $\Delta H = \Delta U + p\Delta V$ then we get $\Delta H = \Delta U$. But in some reaction there is change in number of moles like $$\ce{NH2CN(g) + 3/2O2(g) -> N2(g) + CO2(g)+ H2O(l)}$$ so here $\Delta H = \Delta U + (-0.5)RT$.

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost your $-0.5$ should have units of moles (i.e. should be $-0.5~\mathrm{mol}$). Don't leave out units. They're important.

> $$\Delta H = \Delta U + p\Delta V$$

If you were not taught what conditions this equation holds true, shame on your teacher. If you were taught it, you should probably try to remember that this holds for **constant pressure.**

In general

$$\begin{align}
H &= U + pV \\
H_2 - H_1 &= (U_2 + p_2V_2) - (U_1 + p_1V_1) \\
&= (U_2 - U_1) + (p_2V_2 - p_1V_1) \\
\Delta H &= \Delta U + \Delta (pV)
\end{align}$$

**Only under constant pressure** $p_2 = p_1 = p$ does this simplify to

$$\begin{align}
\Delta H &= (U_2 - U_1) + (pV_2 - pV_1) \\
&= \Delta U + p(V_2 - V_1) \\
&= \Delta U + p\Delta V \\
\end{align}$$

If this is not true (*and think about it*, if your volume is constant, then what do you think is happening to the pressure inside the calorimeter?), then you may use the **ideal gas approximation**

$$p_2V_2 = n_2RT_2;\quad  p_1V_1 = n_1RT_1$$

and if you further assume **constant temperature** $T_2 = T_1 = T$ (which is probably not true, but it is close enough to the truth since the heat capacity of a calorimeter is usually large leading to a very small difference between $T_2$ and $T_1$), then

$$\begin{align}
\Delta H &= (U_2 - U_1) + (n_2RT - n_1RT) \\
&= \Delta U + (n_2 - n_1)RT \\
&= \Delta U + RT\Delta n
\end{align}$$

The further approximation is that the non-gaseous species do not contribute significantly to the $\Delta(pV)$ term, so $\Delta n$ here can be identified with $\Delta n_g$, the difference in the number of moles of gas.

### TL;DR

$$\color{red}{\textbf{Learn when the equations you are using are appropriate to use.}} \\
\large\color{red}{\textbf{Don't just blindly use them!}}$$

Comment: I wish I could frame the lines in red and put them up on a banner on the top of this site...

Comment: While I agree with your 'red' comment we do not help ourselves when teaching and often use a variety of notation, e.g. such as G, $\Delta G$ and dG or create equations out of 'thin air' as $dU=(\partial U/\partial T)_VdT+(\partial U/\partial V)_TdV$. As an example, consider a change at constant volume then $\Delta V =0$ and so by the first law $q=\Delta U$. But $\Delta U$ is a function of state and *q* a path variable so how can this be? The answer  is that the path is fixed so *q* is now a path function and should be changed, say, to $q_V$ . So the possibilities for confusion are many.